# sqlite3 update where table is variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I was wondering if it is possible to update a table, using a variable table name. This is what I have tried so far:

code:

```
self.cur.execute("UPDATE (?) SET Balance = (?) WHERE ID = (?)", [table_name, newbal, self.ID])
```

My code produces the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Balance
```

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE StaffTable (
ID         STRING REFERENCES Accounts (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
                  PRIMARY KEY,
First_name TEXT,
Last_name  TEXT,
Balance    STRING,
Allowance  STRING
);

CREATE TABLE StudentTable (
ID         STRING PRIMARY KEY
                  REFERENCES Accounts (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
First_name TEXT,
Last_name  TEXT,
Balance    STRING
);
```

Comment: first check `table_name` - maybe you use wrong table.

Comment: table_name = "StaffTable"   , this does seem like it could produce an error how could i set it correctly if it is wrong?

Comment: then try `?` without `()`

Comment: You can't use query parameters as table or column identifiers. Even if you could, computing table names at runtime usually indicates that you're also creating tables at runtime, which has many practical issues (though in your case it's not too bad)